# Counting the number of digits in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

Here is my code

```
select len(cast(code as float)),code 
from tbl1
where code is not null
```

and this is the output:

[image]

I want a count of digits in the code column.
I don't understand why the last one is counted as 12 and not 8?

Comment: Try `select cast(code as float)` to see what it's getting the length of.

Comment: might there be blank spaces to the right?

Comment: There was actually an error in the loading of the table. In this situation, should I just delete the post?

Answer (score 5):

Cast it as an `int` instead:

```
select len(cast(code as int)), code 
from tbl1
where code is not null;
```

Presumably, some sort of decimal values are getting counted.

Answer (score 4):

Get the number's power of 10 and add 1. This works either if ints or reals to count the number of digits of the whole number part (note using LOG10 only works on positive numbers so I have applied ABS to get around this issue, may not be required for your data):

```
SELECT code, CASE WHEN Number = 0 THEN 1
                  ELSE FLOOR(LOG10(ABS(code))) + 1 AS NDigits
FROM tbl1
```