# SQL for string manipulation of numeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I am trying to write a sql query for doing string manipulation on 2 columns.

So basically the goal is , that for values of 2 different columns, if the length of the numbers is the same and both are of opposite signs, i have to drop insignificant digits starting from the left. Here is an example to help make it a little clear.

if I have 2 numbers, lets say 1123457 and -1124678, the query should return 3457 and -4678. I have a function to do that but it seems to be taking forever since thats doing string manipulation on a row by row basis. Does anybody have any experience doing that? And if so, can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your existing code?

Comment: can you please post some sample data and desired results .. just to be clear on what you want to achieve..

Comment: There definitely a more efficient to accomplish this, and definitely try to avoiding while loops in SQL. Will try to get yo an answer in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the "-" with an empty string, can you use the ABS function instead? I feel like that would be a lot quicker.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

First of, when deciding to write some complex logic you need to find out what tools are available. String manipulations to process numbers should raise code smell alarm bells in all languages.

You can read up on various SQL Server functions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/mathematical-functions-transact-sql

You can also search the Internet for solutions. I had to search for "sql server find number of digits in number" to find this article:
[Counting the number of digits in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007223/counting-the-number-of-digits-in-column)

The code:

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE ( Num1 INT, Num2 INT )
INSERT INTO @Sample
VALUES( 1123457, -1124678 ), ( -1223457, 1124678 ), ( -1223457, -1124678 ), ( 0, 0 )

;WITH Step1 AS(
    -- Determine Number properties
    SELECT Num1, Num2, ABS( Num1 ) AS Num1Abs, ABS( Num2 ) AS Num2Abs,
        SIGN( Num1 ) AS Num1Sign,
        SIGN( Num2 ) AS Num2Sign,
        ( CASE WHEN LEN( ABS( Num1 )) = LEN( ABS( Num2 )) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS LenMatchFlag
    FROM @Sample 
),
Step2 AS(
    -- Find all possible significant digit matches of two numbers
    SELECT Num1, Num2, Num1Abs, Num2Abs, Num1Sign, Num2Sign, NumDigits,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Num1Abs, Num2Abs ORDER BY NumDigits ASC ) AS BestMatch
    FROM Step1
        -- Possible number of significant digits
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) AS NumLengths(NumDigits)
    WHERE 
        LenMatchFlag = 1
        AND Num1Sign = Num2Sign * -1 AND Num1Sign <> 0
        AND ROUND( Num1Abs, -NumDigits, 1 ) = ROUND( Num2Abs, -NumDigits, 1 )
),
Step3 AS(
    -- Return the best match, and calculate outpu values
    SELECT (( Num1Abs - ROUND( Num1Abs, -NumDigits, 1 )) * Num1Sign ) AS NewNum1,
        (( Num2Abs - ROUND( Num2Abs, -NumDigits, 1 )) * Num2Sign ) AS NewNum2,
        *
    FROM Step2
    WHERE BestMatch = 1
)
SELECT 'Changed', NewNum1, NewNum2, Num1, Num2
FROM Step3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'UnChanged', Num1, Num2, Num1, Num2
FROM Step1
WHERE NOT(
    LenMatchFlag = 1
    AND Num1Sign = Num2Sign * -1 AND Num1Sign <> 0
    )
```

Output:

```
          NewNum1     NewNum2     Num1        Num2
--------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Processed 3457        -4678       1123457     -1124678
Processed -223457     124678      -1223457    1124678
UnChanged -1223457    -1124678    -1223457    -1124678
UnChanged 0           0           0           0
```

**Note:** If you have numbers with more than 9 digits, you need to add more values to `NumLengths` list

**Note2:** to see what values are returned by each calculation step you can change the last `SELECT` to return a specific table e.g. `SELECT * FROM Step1`

Comment: Thank you so much Alex. this is exactly what I wanted! just another quick question though  I am kinda having a hard time converting this into a function. I need it as a function so I can join it to the table. Any thoughts on how thats possible?

Comment: @Dennyc, what are the problems you are facing?

Comment: so basically i am trying to join that to an existing table and replace the new values: something like this:                                                
            select a.first_clm, a.second_column, b.newnum1, b.newmum2
      from table1 a
     join tvf_function1(newnum1,newnum2) b

Comment: This code is a demonstration of the logic. Converting it to the function should be straight forward. You may need to to replace `Sample` table with your function input parameters and adjust the final query to match your output requirements.

Comment: ya i think I have it now. Thanks again!